# TFS Test Runner has a limit of 100 tests per session when doing manual test run. How to increase this?

Tags: tfs

In TFS (running version 2018 RTW 16.122.27102.1) when I go to Test Plans and select a more than 100 test to run manually I recieve the message:

> Test Runner has a limit of 100 tests per session. Reduce the number of selected tests and try again.

[image]

I do not understand the reasoning for this limit. How do I remove or increase this limit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such configuration in TFS/MTM related to 100 tests limitation.

According to the error info, this may related to the **Microsoft Test Runner** in web portal. Since it's Browser-based test execution.

[image]

You may have to follow the suggestion reduce the number of selected tests in single session and try again.

Comment: So this is a limitation of Test Runner in web portal? Do you know if this is going to be changed in the future because I was under the impression that TFS/VSTS Web Test Portal with Test Runner is intended to be the replacement for MTM.

Comment: @jpishko TFS offer both web-based and client-based solutions for manual testing. The  web-based manual testing solution, which works across all platforms and with all browsers. Yes, it's over Microsoft Test Manager in most scenes. But not every one. For example, use the client  Microsoft Test Manager, to run tests, unlike Test Runner in web portal which  not just capture the pass/fail of steps, comments/attachments and bugs, but also capture diagnostic data during execution, such as screen recording, system info, image action log etc.

Comment: @jpishko Too many tests in a single session may influence the exploratory testing session insights. Take a look at [Get insights across your exploratory testing sessions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/manual-test/insights-exploratory-testing?view=vsts) You could simply separate all tests in multiple sessions not  a single one. Besides, you could also report to TFS Developer Community  https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/topics/tfs.html to double confirm if it's just by designed or a bug.